# How to unblock my requests from my js frontend to my api through nginx with docker-compose?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, cors

Context:
So I am creating a web app for a nonprofit organization. This project started at school and I wanted to use some "new" technologies.

I choosed to create several services and to manage them through docker-compose.
I mainly have these services:

- Backend api with django-rest-framework
- Frontend with vuejs
- reverse-proxy with nginx

Everything is working fine and I'm close to the end of the project. So I wanted to test my architecture on a test environement. The problem is that I'm a big noob concerning deployement and I may took the wrong option.

Here was my thinking: the nonprofit organization doesn't have a lot of money so I tried to test one of the cheapest solution: renting a virtual machine, cloning my project and run on the machine docker-compose.

The problem I am having is that all my requests (except some GET for the css) aren't working in this environement. I have this problem:

- When I reach my home page and I try to fetch some images from my nginx, I immediately have this message in the console: CORS request blocked: CORS request did not succeed.
- After if I want to login, instead of having my POST request, the network tab in firefox shows me that there's only an OPTION that is send but there isn't any answer.

I guess there is a problem with CORS or something like this but as everything is running inside docker, I failed to find the error and a fix. And I don't really understand what is going wrong here. Is it really a CORS problem? Is it linked to docker-compose or the environement as it work perfectly on my pc?

Can anyone help me please?

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres
    networks: 
      - main
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:alpine
    networks: 
      - main

  celery:
    container_name: celery
    build: ./backend
    command: bash -c 'celery worker --app=backend.celery:app --loglevel=info'
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks: 
    - main

  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/prod/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/prod/prod.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - django-static:/usr/src/app/static
      - django-media:/usr/src/app/media
    networks:
      - main

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    command: /start_prod.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - django-static:/backend/static
      - django-media:/backend/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  pg-data:
  django-static:
  django-media:

networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
```

and here is my nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;

    root /dist/;
    index index.html;

    # frontend
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

    # backend urls
    location ~ ^/(admin|api|auth) {

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # static files
    location /static {
      autoindex on;
      alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }

    # media files
    location /media {
      autoindex on;
      alias /usr/src/app/media;
    }
  }
}
```

To be honest as I don't have much experience yet, I followed a lot this project: https://verbose-equals-true.gitlab.io/django-postgres-vue-gitlab-ecs/
But I wanted something different so I only followed the first guides and adapted the following.

I already tried to use django-cors-headers or to add CORS support in the nginx conf like these posts advice:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx
- https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487
  But it didn't solve my solution.

If anyone have an answer or/and advice about how to deploy in a better manner or/and how to improve my architecture, please write me a comment.

Comment: Is your `frontend` a `service` in your `docker-compose` or is it in the `nginx service`?

Comment: It is in the nginx. I used it to serve static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it linked to docker-compose or the environement as it work perfectly on my pc?

I would guess, the hostname/IP you are using on your frontend is wrong. Sounds like you are using `localhost` also known as IPv4 `127.0.0.1` or IPv6 `::1` to send the requests to the test deployment backend.

Should I be right with my guess: I would recommend using environment variables additionally to your start script or in a separate config to specify the environment. Otherwise you could just change the hostname/IP in your code for every request.
Anyhow you have to use the hostname/IP to your test environment.

Comment: That's exact, I am using localhost in my requests.
In that case, should I use the private or public IP?
I'll test both but I don't understand why it isn't working with localhost. Each of my services runs on the same server so isn't localhost refering to that IP address?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the public IP or hostname of your test environment. You are right, both are on the same server. However the frontend is executed on the client side, meaning if I visit your web application it is running and trying to send request to localhost no my machine and not to your test environment. Is it working now?

Comment: Oh God, this is so obvious... I know that js is client-side but I totally forgot it and made the assumption that it is executed server side... Well thank you! I can't believe I got stuck on this stupid mistake for so long ha ha! So in deed, I used the .env files to change the url and it worked!

Comment: Great!! Could you mark my answer :) would be awesome.